# Making chunks of audio files using SoX if start and end times are known

Tags: batch-processing, sox

I have a 10 minute audio which I want to break in chunks of time as follows:
*(the format is mm:ss.frac)*

```
 1. 1.wav -> 00.000 - 20.271
 2. 2.wav -> 20.272 - 47.550
 3. 3.wav -> 47.551 - 01:20.562
```

I tried using the `trim` command like such

> `sox infile outfile trim 0.000 20.271` However the format is `trim start [length]`

Worst case, I will have to calculate the durations for individual chunks. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the simplest solution is to write the command as such:

```
sox infile outfile start =end
```

The audio is not sent to the output stream until the start location is reached and specifying an end location can be done by using the "=" sign with the end time.

So the code would now be, for instance:

```
sox forth.wav 10.wav trim 303.463 =353.790
```

1. **Link to the docs** http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sox.1.html
2. **Relevant excerpt:**

> **trim start [length|=end]**
>   The optional length parameter  gives  the  length  of  audio  to
>                 output  after  the start sample and is thus used to trim off the
>                 end of the audio.  Alternatively, an absolute end  location  can
>                 be  given by preceding it with an equals sign.  Using a value of
>                 0 for the start parameter will allow trimming off the end only.

Comment: Where do you find this info? Please post link to this docs. As I see in your case it's work like **trim start [duration]**

Comment: @DimaMelnik I've updated my answer to include the link and the relevant excerpt.

Comment: Just found that, if you want to several chunks of a file in a single command: `sox infile outfile =s0 =e0 =s1 =e1 =s2 =e2 ...`. Where `s_i`, `e_i` are start and end times, respectively. Also, escape the `=` sign if you are using `zsh`. And of course, use `play infile =s0 =e0 ...` to just play the file at the indicated time spans.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to calculate the length if you want to use sox. You could also use ffmpeg instead which has [atrim](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) filter that supports start/end times.

Comment: I found out that adding an '=' sign to the end time will give you the exact end time instead of taking that value as the duration. Please see my answer